# How to multiply a post to test internal search results?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, search

I'm using two ways to do my search. One, located in `search.php`:

```
<?php /* Search Count */ 

$allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
$key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 

if($wp_query->found_posts<2){
    _e('Pesquisa para');
     _e(''); _e('<span class="search-terms">'); 
    echo $key; _e('</span>'); 
    _e(' &mdash; '); 
    echo $wp_query->found_posts . ' '; 
    _e('resultado');
}else if($wp_query->found_posts<100 && $wp_query->found_posts>1){
    _e('Pesquisa para');
    _e(''); _e('<span class="search-terms">'); 
    echo $key; _e('</span>'); 
    _e(' &mdash; '); 
    echo $wp_query->found_posts . ' '; 
    _e('resultados');
}else{
    _e('Você atingiu o limite de resultados por pesquisa, para');
    _e('<span class="search-terms">'); 
    echo $key; _e('</span>'); 
}

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This is to display a message of how many results were found in a user search.

`$wp_query`, is a global variable, found in the plugin. With that variable, I can find the number of results, using:

```
$wp_query->found_posts;
```

With that, I'm using [Relevanssi Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) to set a number of maximum results per search. To increase performance, I've set the maximum number of results per search to 100.

For testing purposes, I'd like to know, if there's a way, to multiply a post?

For example: I have one post, in my site. Then, somehow (through code), multiply it by 100. So that I'll have 100 posts in my site.

With that, I could check what happens in my theme, when there are 100 or more search results.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are ways to duplicate posts, but I don't think that's what you need.

Check out http://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-content-creator/, which is probably exactly what you're after, and allows you to create many posts at once for test purposes. Otherwise, check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test where you can get test content.